# Junos Pulse users are competing with eachother for VPN connection

Tags: vpn, juniper

We've having the issues described here: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB26822
where one user kicks another user off the VPN when connecting. Our PCs were cloned after the Junos GUID was created. The KB article says to:

---

The Junos Pulse connection configuration, which is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Juniper Networks\ConnectionStore\connstore.dat`, contains the following section:

```
machine 
"local" {
    guid: "9e4898e81ca026623e7fb4c9f4de1f678244fa62"
    pulse-language: "en-US"
}
```

---

I've tried deleting the GUID line from the `connstore.dat file`, but if I restart the Junos client, it sets the same GUID instead of a new one, so the duplicate GUID problem persists.

I also tried deleting the `connstore.bak` file and then deleting the GUID line from connstore.dat, but that still got the same GUID.

Has anyone else run into this and been able to fix it? <strike>I'm guessing the GUID is cached on the VPN server, and when I connect, the client sends some key to lookup the GUID.</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Before you edit `connstore.dat` to delete the GUID line, you must first to go into `Services` and stop `Juniper Unified Network Service`.

Or in Task Manager, you can kill: `dsAccessService.exe` / `Juniper Access Service`

The service will restart itself when you restart the Junos client.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked for me:
I stopped the Juniper Unified Network Service as specified in the Walter Stabosz answer, then I removed guid from the connstore.dat file, but also from the Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Juniper Networks\Device Id, key: DeviceId
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Juniper Networks\Device Id, key: DeviceId
```

After restarting Juniper Unified Network Service and the Junos client the new guid was generated.

Comment: This worked for me but on my system the path was `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Juniper Networks\Device Id`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the registry key and then restart the service. Connstore.Dat will automatically update with a new key after you restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

An KB was created for that on Juniper's website. (http://kb-beta.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25581, now article located there: https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB25581)

I confirm too that now you need to erase too the registry like @tafiq3's told:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Juniper Networks\Device Id
>
> Summary:
>
> This article describes the issue of Junos Pulse being frequently
>   disconnected for multiple Junos Pulse Desktop users.
>
> This issue can occur, if multiple users have the same guid string
>   value for the local machine ID in the Connection Store configuration
>   data file; which is created, when installing Junos Pulse for the first
>   time.
>
> The issue is intermittent and can occur at any time during the
>   session. At other times, the session is not affected and the Junos
>   Pulse user stays connected, until they sign out.
>
> Problem or Goal:
>
> Multiple users report frequent disconnects with the Junos Pulse
>   desktop client that occur randomly.  The following error message is
>   generated on the desktop, when Junos Pulse is disconnected:
>
> Cause:
>
> When deploying Junos Pulse desktop to end-users, if the Junos Pulse
>   client is pre-installed on Windows OS and an image is created from
>   this, which is shared across multiple endpoints, then the local
>   machine ID that gets stored in the Junos Pulse Connection Store
>   configuration data file will be the same for every machine that the
>   image is used on.
>
> The Junos Pulse Secure Access Gateway Series device identifies user
>   sessions that connect with the Junos Pulse clients by the local
>   machine identifier, which is sent to the server, when a connection is
>   established via Junos Pulse. The Junos Pulse Secure Access Gateway
>   Series device will terminate a Junos Pulse session, if another Junos
>   Pulse session is started with the same guid value, for security
>   reasons.
>
> To determine if Junos Pulse users in your environment are affected by
>   this issue, collect the Junos Pulse logs and diagnostics logs from the
>   Junos Pulse client, from each individual client PC. Open the logs and
>   Diagnostics folder from the user's PC and browse to the
>   ConnectionStore folder, which will contain the connstore.dat file.
>   Open this file with a text editor and locate the following parameter:
>
> machine "local" {
>        guid: "d96b50d4275ef266d402348641e6b57b10b48bd3"
>        pulse-language: "en-US" }
>
> If the guid string is identical across multiple client PC's, then this
>   confirms the issue.
>
> Solution:
>
> When deploying Junos Pulse, which is pre-installed for a Windows OS
>   image being shared across multiple endpoints, the guid value for the
>   local machine should be removed from the Junos Pulse configuration
>   file, after installing Junos Pulse; so that the Junos Pulse
>   configuration data files in the root image do not contain a guid value
>   that would be replicated on all machines.  A new and unique guid value
>   will be generated for each user, when Junos Pulse is launched and run
>   for the first time.
>
> Perform the following procedure to reset the guid for users, who have
>   already installed Junos Pulse and have duplicate guid values in the
>   Junos Pulse configuration file or the master image (which is used to
>   pre-image multiple PC's with an image that Junos Pulse has already
>   been pre-installed on):
>   1.When Junos Pulse is installed browse to C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Juniper Networks\Connection Store and open the connstore.dat
>   file in a text editor.
>
> 2.Locate the following parameter:  machine "local" {
>       guid: "41cbc0d2a1a100855755b4355d6d2579836694cd"
>       pulse-language: "en-US" }
>
> 3.Remove the guid value from the parameter by deleting the entire second line. This will change the parameter setting to:
>
> machine "local" {
>       pulse-language: "en-US" }
>
> 4.Save the modified connstore.dat file to the original directory.
>
> Note: It may be necessary to edit the 'connstore.dat' file in a Text
>   Editor, which is 'Run As Administrator', if these changes are locally
>   made from the affected PC; due to the folder and file permissions that
>   are set on the directory.
>
> 5.Go to Task Manager > Services tab, locate and stop the JuniperAccessService service, and/or reboot the PC to restart the
>   service. When the service is restarted and Junos Pulse has been
>   launched again, a new and unique guid will be generated and stored in
>   the user's connstore.dat file.
>
> 6.On Mac OS X the following script can be used:
>
> ## !/bin/bash
>
> ## stop pulse access service
>
> ## remove local guid from connstore.dat
>
> ## restart service plist='/Library/LaunchDaemons/net.juniper.AccessService.plist'
>
> connstore='/Library/Application Support/Juniper Networks/Junos
>   Pulse/connstore.dat' guid=xxx....xxx sudo launchctl unload
>   ${PLIST.EN_US} sudo sed -i .bak "/${GUID.EN_US}/d"
>   "${CONNSTORE.EN_US}" sudo launchctl load ${PLIST.EN_US}
>
> Note: The 'connstore.dat' file also contains the connections that are
>   displayed in the Junos Pulse UI, when it is launched. So, it is
>   recommended that the above procedure be performed to modify only the
>   portion of the 'connstore.dat' file, which was specified above, to
>   resolve this issue; as opposed to deleting the 'connstore.dat' file
>   from the user's PC. If the connstore.dat file is deleted from the PC,
>   the user will need to manually recreate any and all connections that
>   they regularly access.

Answer (score 0):

For a MAC running Junos Pulse 5.x, run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# stop pulse access service
# remove local guid from connstore.dat
# restart service
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.juniper.AccessService.plist
sudo rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/Juniper Networks/Junos Pulse/DeviceId"
sudo sed -i .bak "/guid/d" "/Library/Application Support/Juniper Networks/Junos Pulse/connstore.dat"
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.juniper.AccessService.plist
```

Note:  This script is the version found in the KB (referenced in yagmoth555's answer), but with one mistake fixed.

The link to the KB is now the following:

[KB25581 - [Pulse] Pulse Secure Desktop client is intermittently disconnecting for multiple users at random intervals](https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB25581)